# regex email validation Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my regex for email validation, but I want to restrict consecutive period like I don't want . _ - to be consecutively repeated. Anyone can help me?

```
/^((?:[a-z]+[0-9_\.-]*)+[a-z0-9_\.-]*[a-z0-9])@((?:[a-z0-9]+[\.-]*)+\.[a-z]{2,4})$/
```

for example:
test..test@example.com instead i want test.test@example.com or test_test@example.com test-test@example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex to avoid consecutive period.

```
^(?!.*\.{2})\A\S+@.+\.\S+\z
```

Check it [here](http://rubular.com/)

You can add,

```
^(?!.*\.{2})
```

before any email regex that will work to avoid consecutive dots.